# Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',)': /simple/flask/

Tags: docker, flask

Docker failed when running "RUN pip install flask", content of Docker file is as follows:

```
FROM python:3.4

RUN mkdir /code

COPY app.py /code/app.py

WORKDIR /code

RUN pip install flask redis

CMD ['python', 'app.py']

**When I run in the terminal : "$ sudo docker build -t fig_ex .", it shows:**

Sending build context to Docker daemon 3.072 kB

Step 1 : FROM python:3.4

---> d87c6dbd17a7

Step 2 : RUN mkdir /code

---> Using cache

---> 4049bfe07335

Step 3 : COPY app.py /code/app.py

---> Using cache

---> bbe0353172b6

Step 4 : WORKDIR /code

---> Using cache

---> 2535608c604c

Step 5 : RUN pip install flask redis

---> Running in 4a49dee8c8b1
```

Collecting flask

```
Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f0f88deec18>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',)': /simple/flask/

Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f0f88dee2b0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',)': /simple/flask/

Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f0f88dee908>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',)': /simple/flask/

Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f0f88dd0978>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',)': /simple/flask/

Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f0f8914d630>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',)': /simple/flask/
```

Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement flask (from versions: )

No matching distribution found for flask

The command '/bin/sh -c pip install flask redis' returned a non-zero code: 1

**I have restarted everything, error still occurs.
my docker version is 1.12.3.**

Thank you !

Comment: Does the above install work outside of Docker - either globally or in a virtualenv?

Comment: what do you mean by "outside of Docker"?  the docker daemon is running, I run "docker build" after editting Dockerfile, then error occurs when collecting flask

Comment: By outside of Docker, I mean just in your shell or command-line. Basically where you'd be doing this stuff before Docker came about.